# Stray vertical line above 965 pixels with border radius in Safari

Tags: html, safari, css

I've noticed that if I have a div with a width greater than 965 pixels and a border radius on less than all 4 corners, there is a stray vertical line in the div. Here's a jsFiddle link... http://jsfiddle.net/Z3vFp/4/. Notice that this only occurs in Safari. Any thoughts? Also note that the 965 pixel threshold may be a little different in jsFiddle.

EDIT: I'm on a Macbook Pro with Retina display. I guess it's an rMBP thing?

EDIT 2: Here's a jsFiddle screencap. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHRNv.png

Comment: Im not seeing it on Safari for Windows (5.1.7).

Comment: Looks fine on an iMac too. Where is the line you're seeing? Can you show a screenshot?

Comment: I don't see anything either (Macbook Pro Retina display 13" here)

Answer (score 10):

add `-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;`

```
.foo {
    width: 966px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
}​
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I would also add `background-clip: padding-box;` for completeness

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this problem on my 13" Mac Book Pro (OSX 10.8) with Safari Version 6.0 (8536.25). So it has nothing to do with retina display. It occurs when you apply border radius only to one, two or three corners. The solution is to apply border radius to all four corners.

This code displays a stray vertical line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color:red}
#myBox {
  width: 960px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myBox">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's only a solution if you want all four borders :/

Comment: In my case, I am only using top-left and top-right.  If I add bottom-left and bottom-right, that does resolve this issue, so this answer does correctly identify that having all four removes the problem.    

However, in my case, and as the earlier comment notes, this does not fix the issue while keeping the same results, since the question is how to fix this issue when having only some of the radii set.  

Note: I am using a 13' Air (not Retina)

Answer (score -1):

i get it on even when all four corners are set to eg: 5px

the question is - do i not use border-radius because apple safari has a bug - or wait for apple to sort it out

i reckon wait for apple to sort it out - serves rich people right while us peasants have to suffers PC's

~(that is a joke before WW3 breaks out)