# What is this vertical transparent line appearing only on Safari Mac?

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I've designed [this page](http://necdoc.com/blog/) on Google Chrome, and it displays nicely.
However if you check it on Safari Mac (Safari Windows displays it well) and it has a strange vertical line :

[image]

The line seems to be transparency of the white area (if I change the background color, it changes the line color).
Another funny thing : there's an horizontal offset where the title is (the line is cut and moved to the left of the page)... a hint ?

I've inspected the elements, but there's no reason I can find.

Any help ?

Comment: On my safari it displays fine.. http://i.imgur.com/Xzk0hhe.png

Comment: Thanks, are you on Mac OS ? I've seen it displays fine on Windows. If yes, which version are you using ?

Comment: Yes, I'm on `OSX 10.8.2` with `Safari 6.0.2 (8536.26.17)`. I know it's a basic question, but have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll check with other people. I tried to clear my cache, but it didn't fix anything, thanks for the suggestion though. It's a (not so) funny issue !

Comment: have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062582/stray-vertical-line-above-965-pixels-with-border-radius-in-safari

Comment: The answer provided in this question fixed it ! Thanks for the resource :-) If you answer the question, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this reply: [Stray vertical line above 965 pixels with border radius in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062582/stray-vertical-line-above-965-pixels-with-border-radius-in-safari)

You should add `-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;` to your containing class.