# Additional white pixel in repetitive use of span tag in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I dont understand why I get an additional white pixel when putting a span tag around single letters. It works on chrome but not on safari. It needs to do something with the number of span tags since it is always at the same position. Here is the code: https://nopaste.me/view/0df8d1e6

And here are some screenshots:

Safari
[image]

Chrome
[image]

In case the link to the full code doesn't work any more here is a shorter version generating the same white pixel in front of the 130.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    span {
      font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    pre {
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    }
    .isConserved {
      background-color: #D8D7D6;
    }
    .isNotConserved {
      background-color: none;
    }
    .isHelix {
      background-color: #E2B8B7;
    }
    .is3_10Helix {
      background-color: #F4BF91;
    }
    .isSheet {
      background-color: #B9DBE5;
    }
    .isRandomCoil {
      background-color: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <pre>
<span>                    <span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isRandomCoil">&nbsp;</span><span class="isRandomCoil">&nbsp;</span><span class="isRandomCoil">&nbsp;</span><span class="isRandomCoil">&nbsp;</span><span class="isRandomCoil">&nbsp;</span><span class="isRandomCoil">&nbsp;</span><span class="isRandomCoil">9</span><span class="isRandomCoil">0</span><span class="isRandomCoil">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">1</span><span class="isHelix">0</span><span class="isHelix">0</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="is3_10Helix">&nbsp;</span><span class="is3_10Helix">&nbsp;</span><span class="is3_10Helix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">1</span><span class="isHelix">1</span><span class="isHelix">0</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">1</span><span class="isHelix">2</span><span class="isHelix">0</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">&nbsp;</span><span class="isHelix">1</span><span class="isHelix">3</span><span class="isHelix">0</span>
</span><span>1 CYP102A1          <span class="isConserved">F</span><span class="isConserved">A</span><span class="isConserved">G</span><span class="isConserved">D</span><span class="isConserved">G</span><span class="isConserved">L</span><span class="isConserved">F</span><span class="isConserved">T</span><span class="isConserved">S</span><span class="isNotConserved">W</span><span class="isConserved">T</span><span class="isConserved">H</span><span class="isConserved">E</span><span class="isNotConserved">K</span><span class="isConserved">N</span><span class="isConserved">W</span><span class="isConserved">K</span><span class="isConserved">K</span><span class="isConserved">A</span><span class="isConserved">H</span><span class="isConserved">N</span><span class="isConserved">I</span><span class="isConserved">L</span><span class="isNotConserved">L</span><span class="isConserved">P</span><span class="isNotConserved">S</span><span class="isConserved">F</span><span class="isConserved">S</span><span class="isConserved">Q</span><span class="isNotConserved">Q</span><span class="isConserved">A</span><span class="isConserved">M</span><span class="isConserved">K</span><span class="isNotConserved">G</span><span class="isConserved">Y</span><span class="isConserved">H</span><span class="isConserved">A</span><span class="isConserved">M</span><span class="isConserved">M</span><span class="isConserved">V</span><span class="isConserved">D</span><span class="isConserved">I</span><span class="isConserved">A</span><span class="isConserved">V</span><span class="isConserved">Q</span><span class="isConserved">L</span><span class="isConserved">V</span><span class="isConserved">Q</span><span class="isConserved">K</span><span class="isConserved">W</span><span class="isNotConserved">E</span><span class="isConserved">R</span>


                </pre> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see a difference. Can you post a picture which highlights the difference

Comment: that is a lot of spans and classes...

Comment: added a square around the pixel. keith do u ve a better solution?

Comment: not sure but maybe this could help ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14501297/6468413

Comment: @Paulie_D addressed your concern and added the smallest code I came up with which will still generate the same white pixel.