# Safari bug with border radius, rounded corners, and strange background repeat

Tags: safari, rounded-corners, css

http://jsfiddle.net/7KDr8/7/

Using Safari 6.0.1, and the following styles, my buttons are rendering in a "buggy" fashion:

This bug only happens in Safari.

[image]

```
.btn {
    height: 40px !important;
    line-height: 40px !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    background-color: #15518d;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #032a52 !important;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    color: #fff !important;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 15px !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-transform: none !important;
    cursor: pointer
}
```

As you can see, the right border of the button seems to start to "repeat" and the left border of the button has some of the color from what is supposed to only be in the bottom.

Has anyone encountered this bug before or know a fix? Thanks!

Comment: You should use Firebug or native dev tools to toggle each line, see where the problem starts.

Comment: I don't see it in Chrome, so it must be specific to Safari.

Comment: i tried in all browsers..no issues..did u try in the latest version of safari..??i tried in 5.1.7..der there is no issues

Comment: The bug is in Safari, as stated in the title and body of the question.

Comment: I see no bug on Safari, which version are you using ?

Comment: The question clearly states: 6.0.1

Comment: Seems to be a bug with that specific version (6.0.1) as the issue cannot be reproduced in the latest version (6.0.5 (7536.30.1)). I would suggest you simply start commenting out declarations in your style block until you find the property (or combination of properties) that cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: Why not just use the `<button>` element?

Answer (score 9):

### Cause

This is a bug related to hardware enabled Safari.

You can verify by disabling the "`Automatic Graphics Switching`" under "`Energy`" in "`System Preferences`" (I am assuming you're on Mac as version 6+ is not available to Windows AFAIK).

As it it a bug it needs to be fixed in the safari code.

### Classic work-around

You *can* store your buttons as images and it will work in all browsers, the old fashion way - a tad more work (and bandwidth), but stable result.

### Clipping

Possible solution -

From this post: [Stray vertical line above 965 pixels with border radius in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062582/stray-vertical-line-above-965-pixels-with-border-radius-in-safari)

Add `-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;` to your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7KDr8/14/)

I don't think there should be problem in normal scenario,

I have just removed `!important` from the properties which should not be dropped.

I have added some hover effect..,

Just make sure if you can remove `padding:20px` or if you can reduce it, that will be a plus point not recommended by me at-least as with line height you are solving the same purpose....

Try to run this one if it helps..

Else if not solved please reply..

Comment: It seems to happen at random. Sometimes when I refresh the page, the button is normal (no bug), but hovering over the button always triggers it.

Answer (score 1):

i think you shoud use

> -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

you will get your required radius.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.selector {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Follow That link: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vTBeC/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.selector {
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 border-radius:10px;
 -khtml-border-radius: 10px; 
}
```

> Also you can follow this link : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3XSJN/1/)